# difference in number of items extracted by SSIS vs. query

Tags: oracle, ssis, data-extraction

I face with a weird issue in SSIS 2016. I have 7928 record in my oracle database and when I use SSIS to extract the same query, it shows me 15982 records. 
Do you have any idea why it is happening?

my source in Oracle DB 10g and I am using SSIS 2016.

[image: image 1]
QUERY

[image: SSIS query]
SSIS query

[image: SSIS output]
SSIS output

Comment: Your query and the tool are connected to different databases -- that would be my first guess.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: they are connected to same database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I found the issue, it was due to use comment inside the query. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to use comments in the query cause the other part of query could not recognize by SSIS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, The code written in SSMS and the code written in SSIS is not always interpreted the same wa. for example you have to use double quotes in SSIS for the same code which as single quotes in SSMS. Also the Functions and Datatypes  used in SSIS and SSMS are somewhat different and should be carefully handled.